# I would need to have an HTML generated email with the following content

Tags: html

I would need to add an html email with the following content in the attached picture. I do not know how to go about adding a blue bar with a text embedded across the body. Can someone please help me?

Much appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i got the exact issue. But in case you are just looking for the HTML help then you can try something like below:-

[image: "Title here"]

Note there are other ways of doing the same using CSS etc.

Comment: Hi Gautam. I am not sure what you mean by "title here".

Comment: Hi did not realize that the HTML tag was not showing properly so I have edited my post now.